# Cell connected by controlsource keeps losing its formula

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, excel-formula, userform

There are two cells in my spreadsheet, one contains input value only (let's say cell_1) and another one (cell_2) has formula referencing to the former one (=cell_1). For convenience, I also create a Userform with a Textbox whose controlsource property is linked to cell_2.

If there is no UserForm, everything works just fine. But with UserForm (shows with vbModeless) and the value in cell_1 changes (no matter it is changed via manual or another VBA subs), the formula in cell_2 will be overwritten by the value of cell_1 and the value in TextBox stops updating.

Has anyone encountered this strange thing?

ps: I've created a simple example, you can download it here
http://wikisend.com/download/192680/Control_Source_Bug_Test.xlsm

[update] 2014/11/29
Although the root cause is still unknown, I found that rowsource property of ListBox works perfectly; the formula of the cell connected by rowsource won't be affected. With proper setting it will look just like TextBox and one can use it as a replacement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think, you should have added your reset formula almpst everywhere.

```
Range("C7").Formula = "=C4"
```

added to the spinbuttons and also into userform textboxes.

 here is [same example sheet which I corrected my way](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qvbrrh80wkemo4m/Control_Source_Bug_Test_v2.xlsm?dl=0) and I think it works. Test and tell me if I am right.

Comment: It works! Thank you!!
But I am still curious about the root cause of this issue, seems like a kernel thing...